# Why is there "will" after "if"?

Tags: if

Why is there "will" after "if"?

> The results will decide if he will win a place at a good university.

As I know it, after "if" we don't use Future Simple, need to use Present Simple.

The sentence is from [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/decide)

Answer (score 2):

Because he has not yet won a place at a good university. That possibility is in the future. "[If](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/if)" is being used to means "whether" (see def. 3 of "[if](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/if)"). So, that sentence is basically saying, "The results will decide *whether* he will win a place at a good university (or will not)."

You could use the *simple present* tense there instead (i.e., "*The results decide* if *he wins* a place at a good university," or even, "The results will decide if *he wins* a place at a good university."), but doing so would still be a in a future sense, in the sense that the simple present tense is sometimes used to express [future events](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-present-future-events/), like winning a place at a good university or not. Since you would be using the simple present to express a future event, it of course wouldn't be wrong to use a future tense to express it.

Comment: I'm afraid, def. 3 doesn't answer on my question.

Comment: As I have understood you, your answer is that no mistake to use Future Simple after "if", isn't it?